# Build combined Objective-C and Swift project for Appium

Tags: ios, swift, appium, xcodebuild, fastlane

I am trying to find an automated way to build a `.app` bundle for automation testers who are using Appium, but our project uses Objective-C and Swift combined, so I *think* it's not straightforward to use `xcodebuild`.

We are using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/) on the project anyway, so I was wondering if I could use `gym`, but [this closed issue](https://github.com/fastlane/gym/issues/98) suggests otherwise.

I am not sure what is the best approach:

- Create a custom lane which does the same as gym but with the changes suggested in that issue.
- Use `xcodebuild` manually, but somehow leverage [this](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/a6641e6e4b990cbf7e421384ada0f11b21d42930/gym/lib/gym/xcodebuild_fixes/swift_fix.rb) `swift_fix.rb` from the `gym` source.

Does anybody know of an existing solution to this problem? Perhaps I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be...